# Meaning of async in DispatchQueue

Tags: swift

I'm watching the concurrent programming talk from WWDC, [found here](https://youtu.be/zfCZTnEZ6Dw?t=234) and I'm a little confused about the meaning of async. In Javascript world, we use "async" to describe processes that happen "out of order" or practically, processes that are not guaranteed to return before the next line of code is executed. However, in this talk it seems as though what the presenter is demonstrating is in fact a series of tasks being executed one after the other (ie. synchronous behavior)

[image]

Then in this code example

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.imagetransform")

queue.async {
    let smallImage = image.resize(to: rect)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.image = smallImage
    }
}
```

This `DispatchQueue` doesn't seem to behave like the FIFO data structure it's supposed to be on first glance. I see that they are passing in a *closure* into the `queue.async` method, but I'm not sure how to add more blocks, or tasks, for it to execute.

I'm guessing the `async` nature of this is similar to Javascript callbacks in the sense that all the variables being assigned in the closure are only scoped to that closure and we can only act on that data within the closure.

Comment: Here "asynchronous" means "runs out of order with respect to the caller", not that you can't set up dependencies. Just as with Promises you can chain operations together.

Answer (score 3):

DispatchQueues are FIFO with regard to the *start* of tasks. If they are concurrent queues, or if you're submitting async tasks, then there's no FIFO guarantee on when they *finish*

> Concurrent queues allow multiple tasks to run at the same time. Tasks are guaranteed to start in the order they were added. Tasks can finish in any order and you have no knowledge of the time it will take for the next task to start, nor the number of tasks that are running at any given time. 
>    - https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: In what scenario would you care about the order in which tasks were started?

Comment: This is only true for concurrent queues, DispatchQueues are serial by default

Comment: @Carpetfizz Keeping latency low for users by first serving those who came first.

Comment: @dan If DispatchQueues are serial by default then what is significance of .sync and .async here? can you please enlighten me?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed Sync: Send an e-mail to a coworker, and stale idly at your screen until you recieve a response. Async: Send an e-mail to a coworker, and carry on with your day. Check back at some later time.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing serial execution with synchronous execution, DispatchQueues are FIFO queues that execute task in the order of their submissions. Now DispatchQueues can be concurrent or serial.

- For serial DispatchQueues tasks are executed one at a time, i.e second task submitted to queue will only start after first task is completed.
- For concurrent DispatchQueues tasks are started as soon as they are submitted.

Using the `async` method to submit the task doesn't wait for submitted task to complete but using `sync` method does. i.e the following code:

```swift
queue.async {
    print("task completed")
}
print("submitted task")
```

will print:

```
submitted task
task completed
```

but the following code:

```swift
queue.sync {
    print("task completed")
}
print("submitted task")
```

will print:

```
task completed
submitted task
```

The limitation in DispatchQueues is that you can only submit synchronous tasks to execute. If you want to execute asynchronous tasks to be executed in a queue you can use [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) and [Operations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation).